# assign two different variables from same line and loop for every line

Tags: bash, loops, awk, command-line, data-manipulation

I am trying to assign variables obtained by awk, from a 2 columned txt file.
To a command, which includes every two value as two variables in it.

For example, the file I use is;

```
foo.txt
10 20
33 40
65 78
```

my command is aiming to print ;

```
end=20 start=10
end=40 start=33
end=78 start=65
```

Basically, I want to iterate the code for every line, and for output, there will be two variables from the two columns of the input file.

I am not an awk expert (I am trying my best), what I could have done so far is this fusion;

```
while read -r line ; do  awk '{ second_variable=$2 ; first_variable=$1 ; }'  ; echo "end=$first_name start=$second_name"; done <foo.txt
```

but it only gives this output;

```
end= start=
```

only one time without any variable. I would appreciate any suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: Note: assigning a variable in `awk` doesn't create/set that variable in the shell (or vide versa). awk and the shell's variables are completely separate.

Comment: I could not understand exactly, cannot I use a variable in a shell script I assigned with an embedded code of awk? Thank you.

Comment: No, you cannot. Each process (whether it's running bash, or `awk`, or whatever) has its own private memory where it keeps whatever variables it may have. You'd need to do something like print the variables from `awk`, capture the output in bash and assign it to bash variables. You also need to be careful not to assign bash variables in a subshell, because the subshell is a separate process from the main shell, so it'd *also* have its own separate variables (see [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024)). One exception is environment variables, which subprocesses get a *copy* of.

Answer (score 4):

In `bash` you only need `while`, `read` and `printf`:

```sh
while read -r start end
do printf 'end=%d start=%d\n' "$end" "$start"
done < foo.txt
```

```
end=20 start=10
end=40 start=33
end=78 start=65
```

---

With `awk`, you could do:

```sh
awk '{print "end=" $2, "start=" $1}' foo.txt
```

```
end=20 start=10
end=40 start=33
end=78 start=65
```

---

With `sed` you'd use regular expressions:

```sh
sed -E 's/([0-9]+) ([0-9]+)/end=\2 start=\1/' foo.txt
```

```
end=20 start=10
end=40 start=33
end=78 start=65
```

Comment: I want to ask something about the first code; 

while read -r start end
do printf 'end=%d start=%d\n' "$end" "$start"
done < foo.txt

Which part is assigning the variables exactly? If I want to to something else rather then just printing them, I need both. Thank you.

Comment: `read -r start end` reads a line from stdin and assigns the first two fields to the variables `$start` and `$end`, respectively (order matters). In order to read in more columns, simply add more variable names. Change the `do` part to whatever you want to do with access to the variables.

Answer (score 0):

Just *in Bash*:

```
while read -r end start; do echo "end=$end start=$start"; done <foo.txt
```

Comment: I suggest to replace `end start` with `start end`.

Answer (score 0):

What about using `xargs`?

```sh
xargs -n2 sh -c 'echo end=$1 start=$2' sh < file.txt
```

## Demo

```sh
xargs -n2 sh -c 'echo end=$1 start=$2' sh <<INPUT
10 20
33 40
65 78
INPUT
```

Output

```
end=10 start=20
end=33 start=40
end=65 start=78
```